# How do i pass array list to a controller

Tags: java, spring

I have a situation where i want to pass a array list to a controller i am attaching my controller and java code below please give me a idea or suggestion to do it
The model class...

```
public class Rules {
String id;
String details;
String parameter;
String value;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
public String getParameter() {
    return parameter;
}
public void setParameter(String parameter) {
    this.parameter = parameter;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public Rules(){}
public Rules(String id,String details,String parameter, String value){
    this.id=id;
    this.details=details;
    this.value=value;
    this.parameter=parameter;

}
```

here is the java class to create a list..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.demo.Rules;

public class CompArray {
public ArrayList<Rules> addRule(){
    ArrayList<Rules> a1= new ArrayList<Rules>();
        Rules rul = new Rules();
        rul.setId("1001");
        rul.setDetails("khagfkj");
        rul.setParameter("lsrkjglkrs");
        rul.setValue("lskdjfk");

    a1.add(rul);

    return a1;

 }
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listRules1(ModelMap model) {
    CompArray obj1 = new CompArray();
    model.addAttribute("listRule1", obj1.addRule());
    return "hello";
}
```

i need a help to do it, please help me, 
Thank You....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using json something like that :

```
 model.addAttribute("listRule1", new JSONArray().addAll(obj1.addRule()));
```

**EDIT:**
 you can do it by passing the whole object in your case you will pass CompArray object and there  while receiving it just invoke your function which will return the arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.demo.Rules;

public class CompArray {
   public ArrayList<Rules> a1= new ArrayList<Rules>();

public CompArray (){
        Rules rul = new Rules();
        rul.setId("1001");
        rul.setDetails("khagfkj");
        rul.setParameter("lsrkjglkrs");
        rul.setValue("lskdjfk");

    a1.add(rul);


 }
public ArrayList<Rules> getRules(){


    return a1;
}
}
```

And controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listRules1(ModelMap model) {
        CompArray obj1 = new CompArray();
        model.addAttribute("listRule1", obj1);
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: so i need to create json array..? how could i do..??

Comment: @ Ahmed Gamal sir its ask me to create a class json array how do i fixed it?? could you tell me in little bit details sir

Comment: @ Ahmed Gamal sir, while i am run the java class its give output like this [com.Rules@2a139a55]

Comment: @Rezaaaa did you take my code copy and paste ? it wouldn't compile ... i thought that you change it  ,, i edited the code now and it will works ,, and about that  [com.Rules@2a139a55] this the object reference of your rul object in the list ,, please show me your code

Comment: sir, i copied same to same ...................................public class CompArray {
    public ArrayList<Rules> a1= new ArrayList<Rules>();

 public CompArray (){
         Rules rul = new Rules();
         rul.setId("1001");
         rul.setDetails("khagfkj");
         rul.setParameter("lsrkjglkrs");
         rul.setValue("lskdjfk");

     a1.add(rul);


  }
 public ArrayList<Rules> getRules(){


     return a1;
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 CompArray obj = new CompArray();
 
}
 }

Comment: where are the lines that give you this output com.Rules@2a139a55] ?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
 CompArray obj = new CompArray();
 System.out.println(obj.getRules());
 

}

Comment: @Rezaaaa this will show the adress not the list values ,,, foreach on the obj.getrules()

foreach(Rules rule:obj.getrules()){
System.out.println(rule.getId());
}

Comment: @ Ahmed Gamal sure sir, sorry i forgot actually

Comment: @ Ahmed Gama, sir i could i ask one more question..??

Comment: @ Ahmed Gama, now i have a situation, that i need to display the value in a table i am doing it in this way but value are not displyed....

Comment: @ Ahmed Gamal , <c:if test="${!empty listRule1}">
     <table  border ="2">
      <tr>
       <th align="center"><b>ID</b></th>
       <th align="center"><b>Details </b></th>
       <th align="center"><b>Parameter </b></th>
       <th align="center"><b>Value</b></th>
      </tr>

Comment: @ Ahmed Gamal      items="${listRule1}" var="obj1">
       <tr>
        <td>${obj1.id}</td>
        <td>${obj1.details}</td>
        <td>${obj1.parameter}</td>
        <td>${obj1.value}</td>
         
       </tr>       
      </c:forEach></c:if>

Answer (score 0):

> Try this using RestController **:**
>
> *@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody* so it will return list
>   in JSON format

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public List<Rules> listRules1(){
        CompArray obj1 = new CompArray();
        return  obj1.addRule();
    }

}
```